# windows programm where main form display on desktop

Tags: c#

Is it possible in Windows 7 to display a form on the desktop behind the icons? The user should only read the content, there is no "animation" or "interaction". If the user can arrange the window, then that would be nice. At this time I can't identify a way to hook up my frame on the desktop.

- I can go through all processes, but can't identify the main "desktop"
  processs or handle.
- Another way could be to create a picture with my information and put
  it in the background. That is not my fovorite.

Which way is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like changing the background image would probably be the easiest way.  I have no idea how you'd get a windows form *under* the desktop icons.

There are a few links out there on how to do this....

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/203bbbd7-2afc-49c2-9a6e-ff857d0bc50b/how-to-change-desktop-wallpaper-in-windows-7-pc-using-cnet?forum=csharpgeneral

Comment: That is not my favorite. If you look at this image: [link](http://www.xemico.com/adc/screenshots/sidebar_desktop_calendar.jpg). How did they do it? A similar solution, that is written in C++ show a image between icon and desktop: [link](http://www.angelcode.com/dev/overlay/)